# Java 2d graphics animation frameworks

Tags: java, swing, layout, frameworks

do you guys know some java framework that can actually do the same stuff as this?

http://cs.joensuu.fi/jeliot/files/jeliotSimple.html

Answer (score 2):

You can use **TimingFramework** http://java.net/projects/timingframework if you use **Swing/Java2D**. The Controls are done in swing and the theater-panel is done in java2D (paintComponent-Methode). See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/index.html for more Infos. If you start a new project use **JavaFX**.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so a late response, but just in case anyone comes searching. I would definitely recommend the [netbeans visual library](http://platform.netbeans.org/graph/).